# Torrenting now fails in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bittorrent, tcpip, sockets

qbitTorrent stopped working in Windows 10, so I uninstalled it, and replaced it with Deluge.

64-bit Deluge fails with
"Unhandled exception in script
Failed to execute script 'deluge-script' due to unhandled exception: [winError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"

Starting Deluge with 'Run as administrator' also did not help.

Using the standard Windows Firewall, & enabled Deluge to use both public & private networks.
Also enabled ports 51000-51010 in Windows Firewall for both TCP and UDP, both Inbound & Outbound.  However, when I went into Preferences, set the incoming port to 51000, then hit Apply then tested that port, it failed.  Changing the Incoming port to 51001, then hit Apply then tested that port, it also failed. Changing ports to Random also did not help.
Rebooting Windows did not help.

Uninstalling Deluge, then installing Transmission, setting Windows Firewall to allow Transmission to send & receive data, then rebooting, resulted in Transmission not able to receive torrents as well.
Multiple torrents, including several from https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=bittorrent did not help.

No 3rd party firewall installed.

```
> netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp    
Protocol tcp Port Exclusion Ranges     
Start Port    End Port     
----------    --------    
50128       50128    
* - Administered port exclusions. 

> netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp    
Protocol tcp Dynamic Port Range    
---------------------------------    
Start Port      : 49152    
Number of Ports : 16384
```

I've run out of ideas of things to try.
How may I find what's blocking torrenting in Windows?

Two different VPNs used. Multiple countries used on each, including endpoints specifically designated for torrenting. Same result. Different computer on same broadband connection torrents AOK.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you do not have a third-party firewall installed? You do not have a problem with a specific program. You have a problem with Winsock. // Please check `netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`. Ports above 50,000 are often reserved by the Internet Connection Sharing service. Also check `netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp`, the ephemeral port range could’ve been changed to something non-standard.

Comment: Your ISP may be blocking torrents. Try a VPN to a country that doesn't block torrents (there are less and less of those).

Comment: Two different VPNs used. Multiple countries used on each, including endpoints specifically designated for torrenting. Same result. Different computer on same broadband connection torrents AOK.